# Find area of cv2.findContours() (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find/calculate the contour area in the next image:

[image: contour]

The goal is to **delete all the dots** you can see in image, so the blobs contoured with an area smaller than a value I give.

[image: removal]

How can I set this ?

This is the **code** I used...

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('source.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

img = cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)

cv2.imshow('contour',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('contour.png',img)
```

...and this is the **source** image:

[image: origin]

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `cv2.contourArea()` to decide which to draw:

```
for contour in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 80:
        cv2.drawContours(im, contour, -1, (255, 255, 255), 3)
```

Comment: But this draw the contours or fill them ? I think is the second...right ?

Comment: Use `-1` as the width to fill them. Perhaps try doing it twice, i.e. one to fill and one with `3`. You could also experiment with blurring the image before threshold.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this. One way would be to find area of bounding rectangle.

```
for contour in contours:
   rect = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
   area = rect[2] * rect[3]
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to delete them ? I suppose an `if` is needed inside the for loop.. I mean, I don't know the instruction. 
I saw [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31433/remove-contoursbounding-rect-with-an-area-n/) that exist a `contours.erase` instruction. But in Python ?

Comment: Was looking for filling the blobs with white but the answer arrived :)

Comment: @Link That's why I left something for you to do but someone else beat you to it. :D